KeyboardAvoidingView not moving the TextArea
In my code the KeyboardAvoidingView is moving just the buttons but not the TextArea... anybody knows why? :( I was trying to move a structure little bit but still got an issue. I am using the gluestack-ui with react-native expo and react-hook-forms.
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="padding"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 100 : 0}
        alignItems="center"
        flex={1}
      >
        <Heading>
          {t("onboarding.step2.title1")}
          <Heading color="$primary500">{t("onboarding.step2.title2")}</Heading>
        </Heading>
        <VStack
          flex={1}
          w={"90%"}
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <FormProvider {...formContext}>
            <VStack w={"100%"} space="lg" mt={20}>
              <Text textAlign="center">
                {t("onboarding.step2.text.eatingGoal")}
              </Text>
              <FormSelect
                name="eatHabitGoal"
                options={[
                  { label: t("eatingGoal.more"), value: "more" },
                  { label: t("eatingGoal.less"), value: "less" },
                  { label: t("eatingGoal.consistent"), value: "consistent" },
                ]}
                placeholder={t("onboarding.step2.label.eatingGoal")}
              />
              <Text>{t("onboarding.step2.text.stress1")}</Text>
              <Text>{t("onboarding.step2.text.stress2")}</Text>

              <StressSlider name="stressRecordValue" label={""} />

              <FormTextArea
                name="stressRecordNote"
                label={t("onboarding.step2.label.stress")}
                placeholder={t("onboarding.step2.label.stressNote")}
              />
            </VStack>
          </FormProvider>
        </VStack>
        <HStack gap={10}>
          <Button
            w={"30%"}
            action="secondary"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Step1")}
          >
            <ButtonIcon as={ChevronLeftIcon} />
            <ButtonText>{t("onboarding.action.back")}</ButtonText>
          </Button>
          <Button w={"30%"} onPress={onPress}>
            <ButtonText>{t("onboarding.action.next")}</ButtonText>
            <ButtonIcon as={ChevronRightIcon} />
          </Button>
        </HStack>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default OnboardingStep2Screen;

tried everyhing in my power
